# Using Link in Mapbox GL JS popup throws Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I'm working on a React (16) SPA with a Mapbox GL JS map with markers and I am trying to render a `Link` in each marker popup, which throws the following:
`Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

This puzzles me as the `Map` component is a child of the `App` component which is wrapped in `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

`Map` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { initalizeMap, getCenter, getZoom, addGeolocateButton, addMarkers, getMarkers } from '../helpers/mapbox';

export default class EventsMap extends Component {
  state = { lng: 2.1700556, lat: 41.3869959, zoom: 11 };

  onMapMove = () => this.setState({
    lng: getCenter('lng', this.map),
    lat: getCenter('lat', this.map),
    zoom: getZoom(this.map),
  });

  renderMap = () => {
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
    this.map = initalizeMap(lng, lat, zoom, this.mapContainer);
    this.map.on('move', () => this.onMapMove());
    addGeolocateButton(this.map);
    const markers = getMarkers(this.props.events);
    addMarkers(markers, this.map);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => this.renderMap();

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='events-map'>
        <div ref={(el) => this.mapContainer = el} className='mapContainer' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`mapbox.js` helper imports and `addMarkers` declaration:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

export const addMarkers = (markers, map) => {
  markers.features.forEach((marker) => {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    const { _id, name, place } = marker.properties;
    const markerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const markerContents = <div><Link to={`/events/${_id}`}><h3>{name}</h3></Link><p>{place}</p></div>;
    ReactDOM.render(markerContents, markerDiv);
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
      .setDOMContent(markerDiv))
      .addTo(map);
  })
};
```

There's no problem using an anchor to an external URL, e.g.:
`const markerContents = <div><a href={`https://google.com`}><h3>{name}</h3></a><p>{place}</p></div>;`

But I need to use `Link` for internal links to avoid redirects, reloads, etc. Why isn't `Link` picking up the `Router` context?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get `<Link>` from `react-router-dom` to work but instead simply wrapped the export of the parent `Map` component with `withRouter` HoC, passed `this.props.history` into `addMarkers`, attached an event listener to the popup contents and pushed to the history object onClick in order to redirect:

```
export const addMarkers = (markers, map, history) => {

markers.features.forEach((marker) => {
    const onClick = (e) => {
      const { _id } = marker.properties;
      history.push(`/events/${_id}`);
    }

    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    const { name, place, rank } = marker.properties;
    el.style.backgroundImage = `url(/markers/${rank + 1}.svg)`;
    const popupContainer = document.createElement('div');
    const popupContents = <div><button onClick={onClick}><h3>{name}</h3></button><p>{place}</p></div>;
```

Code is a bit evolved vs. what I wrote earlier above, but the point is no need to use `Link` when a simple event listener with the history object will do.